# Error using GWT openlayers MapWidget

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, maps, openlayers, gwt-openlayers

Im trying to create a website with a map using GAE and the GWT openlayers library. Im trying to implement it by using a MapWidget in the SiteNameWidget.ui.xml file, but i get the error below.

I've managed to get it working by using the RootPanel.get().add(MapWidget) approach, but i would like to be able to use the XML file approach, as is seems to be easier to manipulate the layout this way.

Anyone?

> org.gwtopenmaps.openlayers.client.MapWidget has no default (zero args) constructor. To         fix this, you can define a @UiFactory method on the UiBinder's owner, or annotate a constructor of MapWidget with @UiConstructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that, because a MapWidget can only be instantiated with arguments, you cannot just declare it as a @UiField in your view and rely on GWT to instantiate it using a default constructor.

Instead, you have to provide either a constructor (if you're specializing a widget) or a factory method that will be called to instantiate your MapWidget appropriately (with MapOptions as a argument in this case).

For instance, add:

```
@UiFactory MapWidget createMapWidget() {  // The method name is irrelevant
   MapOptions opts = MapOptions.newInstance();
   options.setScrollWheel(false);         // Some sample customization. You may use fields initialized in your actual view constructor (which is called before) to do so.
   return new MapWidget(opts);
}
```

See http://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder?#Using_a_widget